# Calculate estimate of remaining download time

Tags: c#

Here is my estimate time code. It is working but there is a mistake in the time.

```
if ((DateTime.Now - _startDate).Seconds > 0)
{
    kbPerSecond = (int)((100 * 1000) / 8);
}
long sent = (TotalBytes - BytesRead);
long remainingseconds = sent / kbPerSecond;
string remainingTimeDisplay = string.Empty;
if (remainingseconds > 0)
{
    if (remainingseconds > 60)
    {
        if (remainingseconds > 3600)
        {
            remainingTimeDisplay += ((int)(remainingseconds) / 3600).ToString("n0") + " Hours, ";
            remainingseconds %= 3600;
        }
        remainingTimeDisplay += (((int)remainingseconds) / 60).ToString("n0") + " Minutes,  ";
        remainingseconds %= 60;
    }
    remainingTimeDisplay += ((int)remainingseconds).ToString("n0") + " Seconds remaining";
    lbl_estimate.Text = remainingTimeDisplay;
}
```

The problem lies in that after the download completes, the estimated time will be displayed as '1 sec remaining' instead of zero.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of mistake? since you have the "kbPerSecond" obviously hardcoded to some value '12500', no wonder that your estimation does not match the reality in most of the cases. Or maybe you mean something else?

Comment: You should tell us what output you are getting, and how it differs from what you expect. Otherwise, this question will most likely get closed for being non-constructive.

Comment: @JohnWillemse after the download completed the estimate time will be 1 sec remaining ..

Comment: what is **TotalBytes and BytesRead** ?

Answer (score 3):

You change text only if you have `remainingseconds` more than 0. You need to do `else` on 1st `if` so you need something like:

```
    if (remainingseconds > 0)
                {
                    if (remainingseconds > 60)
                    {
                        if (remainingseconds > 3600)
                        {
                            remainingTimeDisplay += ((int)(remainingseconds) / 3600).ToString("n0") + " Hours, ";
                            remainingseconds %= 3600;
                        }
                        remainingTimeDisplay += (((int)remainingseconds) / 60).ToString("n0") + " Minutes,  ";
                        remainingseconds %= 60;
                    }
                    remainingTimeDisplay += ((int)remainingseconds).ToString("n0") + " Seconds remaining";
                    lbl_estimate.Text = remainingTimeDisplay;
                }
     else
           lbl_estimate.Text = "0 seconds";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data rate is a constant

```
kbPerSecond = (int)((100 * 1000) / 8);
```

That can't be right.

Comment: you need to *calculate* the kb per second.  That would be kb transferred divided by the number of seconds the transfer has been running.  So you also need to mark the start time of the transfer, and then calculate the time difference each time.

Comment: i marked the start time in code . i only wanna know the mistake

Comment: This is not a real answer. This only explains why the calculated estimation differs from reality, but DOES NOT explain why the calculation stops at **one second instead of zero**. Author stated that problem in the comments.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl true - it's a partial answer.  TRMI's answer nails that angle actually so I'm going to +1 there.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify this you should extract out all the logic for formatting the duration string. That logic doesn't belong mixed up with the rest of the function!

Also, you can simplify it by using [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/269ew577.aspx):

```
public static string FormatDurationSeconds(int seconds)
{
    var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
    string result = "";

    if (duration.TotalHours >= 1)
        result += (int) duration.TotalHours + " Hours, ";

    result += String.Format("{0:%m} Minutes, {0:%s} Seconds", duration);
    return result;
}
```

After you've done that, it should make it easier to see why the number of seconds is wrong.